# Where do I find my bookmarks in my old homefolder and where do I put them in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, bookmarks

I would have just upgraded but everything fell apart during the process.  I think I saved everything off the drive.  Now I'm trying to put it back together with 12.  Where can I find my bookmarks in 10.04, and where do I put them in 12.04?

Thanks

Comment: depending what your browser was and what your browser is now

Comment: Was and still is firefox

Answer (score 1):

They should be here: .mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default/.

This xxxxx stuff is a random string of 8 characters.

If you don't see ".mozilla" folder in your old home folder you have to make nautilus to show you also hidden folders:
http://www.techheadz.co.uk/253.html

Answer (score 0):

When this happen , i generally look for the config directory of firefox in the old home folder and copy it to the new , it usually is .mozilla/firefox.

1)backup your current .mozilla/firefox directory

2) erase you current .mozilla/firefox

3) copy the old one to the current one

4) test it via firefox

They're are other ways to do it but i found it the most easy one

Answer (score 0):

Small guide for your situation by Mozilla:
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles

Which files have what data:
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Recovering%20important%20data%20from%20an%20old%20profile#w_bookmarks-and-browsing-history